# iPhone facebook app: wall post won't appear on news feed

Tags: ios4, facebook, facebook-graph-api, nsmutableurlrequest

I have an iPhone app, which posts messages to Facebook me/feed via NSMutableURLRequest and it works fine, with one exception, app posts appear on user wall, but NOT in the News Feed, so their friends don't see them.

How is that possible?

I request the publish_stream permission for the app, as I thought it would be enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what was the cause of the issue, but I resolved it by creating a new Facebook App, with new ID. The same scripts that only posted to the wall started posting to the news feed on the new App ID.